# textbox making links visible using if else statements , javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

Is there a way in which, instead of opening the links on a new page, the following code could make links visible on the same page?  For example, if I write "project" in the text field and press the submit button, the **project.htm** link becomes visible on the page; and if I write "under" in the textbox and press submit button then **underconstruction.htm** link becomes visible.

```
    <script Language="JavaScript">
    <!--
        function Blank_TextField_Validator() {
            // Check the value of the element named text_name from the form named text_form
            if (text_form.text_name.value == "") {
                // If null display and alert box
                alert("Please fill in the text field.");
                // Place the cursor on the field for revision
                text_form.text_name.focus();
                // return false to stop further processing
                return (false);
            }
           // If text_name is not null continue processing
           if (text_form.text_name.value == "project")
               window.open('project.htm');
           else if (text_form.text_name.value == "under")
               window.open('underconstruction.htm');
           else
               alert("Invalid keyword!");
           return (true);
        }
    -->
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a trick question .. can't you just do this?

**Script**

```
if (text_form.text_name.value == "project")
    document.getElementById('project_link').style.display = 'block';
else if (text_form.text_name.value == "under")
    document.getElementById('construction_link').style.display = 'block';
else
    alert("Invalid keyword!");
return (false);
```

**Markup**

```
<a id='project_link' href='project.htm' style='display: none;'>project</a>
<a id='construction_link' href='underconstruction.htm' style='display: none;'>construction</a>
```

Comment: can you please write the complete code, because i am not getting where to add the markup section.

Comment: @JavariaShah that would just be with the rest of your markup (wherever **<form name='text_form' ...>** is).

Comment: you mean here? its not working in here.                                  <body>
<form name="text_form" method="get" action="#" 
onsubmit="return Blank_TextField_Validator()">
<a id='project_link' href='project.htm' style='display: none;'>project</a>
<a id='construction_link' href='underconstruction.htm' style='display: none;'>construction</a>
<input type="text" name="text_name" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

Comment: Yes, exactly what I mean.  You also have to make sure to return **false** so the form doesn't submit.  Please see my update above (also fixed a typo).